# Error When Making Get Request & How To Display Data Once Received

Tags: json, swift, api, swiftui, get

I am getting the following error when making a get request:

```
Thread 3: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Data model + get request model below:

```
struct Get: Codable, Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var meals: [String: String?]
}



class Api {
func getData(completion: @escaping ([Get]) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php") else {return}
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        let get = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Get].self, from: data!)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(get)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

}

Example View:

```
struct apitestview: View {

@State var getRecipe: [Get] = []

var body: some View {
    List(getRecipe) { get in
        Text("placeholder") //once the data is received, how will I display the data here?
        
    }
    .onAppear() {
        Api().getData { (get) in
            self.getRecipe = get
        }
    }
}
```

}

Additionally, once the data is received how can I display it in the view? The nested JSON structure confuses me. I am quite new to get requests. It does not need to be displayed in a list, it can just be one giant `Text()` element.

Below is the sample JSON object:

```
{
"meals": [
    {
        "idMeal": "52858",
        "strMeal": "New York cheesecake",
        "strDrinkAlternate": null,
        "strCategory": "Dessert",
        "strArea": "American",
        "strInstructions": "Position an oven shelf in the middle of the oven. Preheat the oven to fan 160C/conventional 180C/gas 4. Line the base of a 23cm springform cake tin with parchment paper. For the crust, melt the butter in a medium pan. Stir in the biscuit crumbs and sugar so the mixture is evenly moistened. Press the mixture into the bottom of the pan and bake for 10 minutes. Cool on a wire rack while preparing the filling.\r\nFor the filling, increase the oven temperature to fan 200C/conventional 240C/gas 9. In a table top mixer fitted with the paddle attachment, beat the soft cheese at medium-low speed until creamy, about 2 minutes. With the mixer on low, gradually add the sugar, then the flour and a pinch of salt, scraping down the sides of the bowl and the paddle twice.\r\nSwap the paddle attachment for the whisk. Continue by adding the vanilla, lemon zest and juice. Whisk in the eggs and yolk, one at a time, scraping the bowl and whisk at least twice. Stir the 284ml carton of soured cream until smooth, then measure 200ml/7fl oz (just over 3⁄4 of the carton). Continue on low speed as you add the measured soured cream (reserve the rest). Whisk to blend, but don't over-beat. The batter should be smooth, light and somewhat airy.\r\nBrush the sides of the springform tin with melted butter and put on a baking sheet. Pour in the filling - if there are any lumps, sink them using a knife - the top should be as smooth as possible. Bake for 10 minutes. Reduce oven temperature to fan 90C/conventional 110C/gas 1⁄4 and bake for 25 minutes more. If you gently shake the tin, the filling should have a slight wobble. Turn off the oven and open the oven door for a cheesecake that's creamy in the centre, or leave it closed if you prefer a drier texture. Let cool in the oven for 2 hours. The cheesecake may get a slight crack on top as it cools.\r\nCombine the reserved soured cream with the 142ml carton, the sugar and lemon juice for the topping. Spread over the cheesecake right to the edges. Cover loosely with foil and refrigerate for at least 8 hours or overnight.\r\nRun a round-bladed knife around the sides of the tin to loosen any stuck edges. Unlock the side, slide the cheesecake off the bottom of the tin onto a plate, then slide the parchment paper out from underneath.",
        "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/swttys1511385853.jpg",
        "strTags": "Desert,Dairy,Pudding,Cake,Breakfast",
        "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tspdJ6hxqnc",
        "strIngredient1": "Butter",
        "strIngredient2": "Sour Cream",
        "strIngredient3": "Sugar",
        "strIngredient4": "Cream Cheese",
        "strIngredient5": "Caster Sugar",
        "strIngredient6": "Plain Flour",
        "strIngredient7": "Lemon Juice",
        "strIngredient8": "Eggs",
        "strIngredient9": "Sour Cream",
        "strIngredient10": "Sour Cream",
        "strIngredient11": "Caster Sugar",
        "strIngredient12": "Lemon Juice",
        "strIngredient13": "",
        "strIngredient14": "",
        "strIngredient15": "",
        "strIngredient16": "",
        "strIngredient17": "",
        "strIngredient18": "",
        "strIngredient19": "",
        "strIngredient20": "",
        "strMeasure1": "85g",
        "strMeasure2": "140g",
        "strMeasure3": "1tbsp",
        "strMeasure4": "900g",
        "strMeasure5": "250g",
        "strMeasure6": "3 tbs",
        "strMeasure7": "1 ½ teaspoons",
        "strMeasure8": "3 Large",
        "strMeasure9": "250ml",
        "strMeasure10": "150ml",
        "strMeasure11": "1 tbsp",
        "strMeasure12": "2 tsp",
        "strMeasure13": "",
        "strMeasure14": "",
        "strMeasure15": "",
        "strMeasure16": "",
        "strMeasure17": "",
        "strMeasure18": "",
        "strMeasure19": "",
        "strMeasure20": "",
        "strSource": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2869/new-york-cheesecake",
        "strImageSource": null,
        "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
        "dateModified": null
    }
]
```

}

I did ask a similar question not too long ago, which helped point me in the right direction with this issue. I am still unable to figure this one out. Any thoughts?

Additional info:

Image of where nil reference is being thrown:

[image]

Edit 2 - Posting new version of code:

```
class Api {
func getData(completion: @escaping (Get) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php") else {return}
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        let get = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Get.self, from: data!)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(get)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

}

```
struct apitestview: View {

@State var getRecipe: Get 

var body: some View {
    //List(getRecipe) { get in
        Text("placeholder")
        
    //}
    .onAppear() {
        Api().getData { (get) in
            self.getRecipe = get
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give more context where the nil value is being thrown. My guess is the “data” variable is coming in nil but you’re force unwrapping it.

Comment: Also you’re decoding of [Get].self should be Get.self. You’re not getting back an array of dictionary of meals you’re just getting back a dictionary of meals.

Comment: Justin, I have added an image of where it is being thrown.

Comment: I would change the `decode([Get].self...)` to `decode(Get.self...` first (see my above comment. That’s definitely part of the issue. Also FYI for production level code you should not force unwrap unless you know a value will be there. Additionally for HTTP requests you’ll want to very they were successful before unwrapping the data - see the other parameters of dataTask.

Comment: Justin, I have added the refined code based on your comments. Please see above. I am still getting unexpectedly found nil at the same location. Thoughts?

Comment: What did I tell you earlier about unwrapping an optional value?  Go ahead and have a force-unwrapping day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code to help you out. You can easily refactor this into your "Api" class and your "Get" thing.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct MealResponse: Codable {
    var meals: [[String: String?]]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var meals = [[String: String?]]()
    @State var firstMeal = [String: String?]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(firstMeal.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                VStack {
                    Text(key)
                    Text((firstMeal[key] ?? "") ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
        // if using Swift 5.5 ios-15
        //        .task {
        //            let response: MealResponse? = await fetchMeals()
        //            if let resp = response, let firstOne = resp.meals.first {
        //                meals = resp.meals
        //                firstMeal = firstOne
        //            }
        //        }
        .onAppear { loadData() }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php") else {
            print("Your API end point is Invalid")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MealResponse.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let firstOne = response.meals.first {
                            meals = response.meals
                            firstMeal = firstOne
                        }
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    // if using Swift 5.5 ios-15
    func fetchMeals<T: Decodable>() async -> T? {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                // throw URLError(.badServerResponse)   //  todo
                print(URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return nil
            }
            let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            return results
        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This worked - thanks a lot! The data does return a little strangely, but I will try and format it. If I have additional questions about formatting, I will post a new question.

Comment: @nickreps, you may want to checkout my new test at: "https://github.com/workingDog/FreeMeal"  I didn't know this meal thing existed, interesting...

Comment: that is an excellent resource. Thanks so much!